# Cannot read text file in Shift JIS cp392 encoding

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have problem when read a text file in Shift JIS cp392 encoding in Windows Store app.
I use this code to read the text file:

```
var streamOpenedFile = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

using (var inputOpenedFile = streamOpenedFile.GetInputStreamAt(0))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputOpenedFile.AsStreamForRead(), Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        fileContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}
```

But the string I received in fileContent is only a strange character and does not look like string when I open it with Notepad.
Can anyone help me solve this issue?
Thank a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to have marked the input stream as UTF-8, that means the input stream will be interpreted as UTF-8 not Shift JIS. If you wish for it to be interpreted as Shift JIS you need to change the encoding for `reader`.

```
var streamOpenedFile = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

using (var inputOpenedFile = streamOpenedFile.GetInputStreamAt(0))
{
    using (StreamReader reader =
          new StreamReader(
             inputOpenedFile.AsStreamForRead(),
             Encoding.GetEncoding(932))
    {
        fileContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I caught the exception: '392' is not a supported encoding name. I try to pass "Shift_JIS" into GetEncoding function and see it works as well. Now I understood how to read it, but I still consider whether we can know about the Encoding of text file?

Comment: 392 is not the Shift JIS code page 932 is... my mistake for not checking that. Sadly there is no way to check the encoding other than brute force unless the document format is something like HTML which specifies a series of steps to detecting the document encoding. The better choice is to always use UTF-8 for saved text files if possible.